# Async/await with VueX and a service pattern

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, promise, vuex

I came across [this](https://github.com/Code-Pop/Vuex_Fundamentals/blob/master/src/store/index.js) repo which creates a service to handle calls to an API. I really like this pattern, but was wondering if I would need to use async for this pattern (My doubts stem from the fact that the commit is wrapped in a `then` function.
To give you more context:

---

A typical VueX action looks like this:

```js
createEvent({ commit }, event) {
  return EventService.postEvent(event)
    .then(() => {
      commit('ADD_EVENT', event)
      commit('SET_EVENT', event)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw error
    })
}
```

And the service file looks like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})

export default {
  getEvents() {
    return apiClient.get('/events')
  },
  getEvent(id) {
    return apiClient.get('/events/' + id)
  },
  postEvent(event) {
    return apiClient.post('/events', event)
  }
}
```

---

Typically in my code I have been doing something like this:

```js
async getSomething({ commit }, id) {
  const { data, message } = await getSomethingRequest(id);

  if (data) {
    commit('SAVE_SOMETHING', data);

  } else {
    commit('HANDLE_RESPONSE_ERROR', message);
  }
},
```

Any my API call for `getSomethingRequest` would look like this:

```js
export const getSomethingRequest = async (id) => {
  try {
    const response = await instance.get(`/somethings/${id}`);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

---

I'm fairly new to javascript, so apologies if this is a very basic question, but I'm still a bit confused with how async works, especially when trying to decouple it from some of the Vue magic.

So my question is: If I implemented the service pattern, would I need to make the requests async? Or because it uses `then` there would be no need?
It's a bit hard to tell the consequences since the requests happen quite quickly, but a follow up question: If it is needed and I don't add the async what would happen under the hood?
Would my vue app essentially freeze until a response is returned or would everything continue to work as expected, only coming back to the function after the request's response is returned in order to execute the content of the `then` function?

Comment: if instance.get returns a promise then async/await in getSomethingRequest is useless, you should do that part in getSomething

Comment: Oh! That makes sense. Thanks for that! I'll need to refactor that :p

Comment: async/await is sugar syntax for raw promises and `then`. Everything that can be done with `await`, can be done with `then`. Raw promises are prone to newbie mistakes, but here they were used correctly. *Would my vue app essentially freeze until a response is returned* - JS doesn't work like that. Essentially, you have to wait for a promise at some point. In case of Vuex, this point is `await dispatch('createEvent')`. This can make Vue wait for it before rendering when suspense is used, see https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/suspense.html#introduction